# How to add a font to react-native-macos?

Tags: react-native, fonts, react-native-vector-icons, react-native-macos

I am trying to install react-native-vector-fonts and have followed the instructions at

https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons

I then imported the font:

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
Icon.loadFont();
```

and then use it in the following way:

```
 <Icon name="rocket" size={30} color="#900" />
```

However I get the following error: `Unrecognized font family FontAwesome`.

I have also followed the instructions at:

https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#red-screen-with-unrecognized-font-family-error-on-ios

but I am still receiving the error `Unrecognized font family FontAwesome`.

I have ensured the following exists in my macos/myapp-macOS/Info.plist file:

```
    <key>ATSApplicationFontsPath</>
    <array>
        <string>Fonts</string>
    </array>
```

How do I solve this?